# How to Bind the Delete Button in MonoTouch TableView using MVVM

Tags: ios, mvvm, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I need to bind the delete button appears in the Table View of the Mono touch to my command in my ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to change your MyItemType (used in the ViewModel's collection) so that it has a `PleaseDeleteMeCommand`, then call it like:

```
        public override void CommitEditingStyle(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCellEditingStyle editingStyle, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete)
            {
                var item = (MyItemType)GetItemAt(indexPath);
                item.PleaseDeleteMeCommand.Execute(null);
            }
            base.CommitEditingStyle(tableView, editingStyle, indexPath);
        }
```

Another way would be to add the command to the owning ViewModel instead.

```
        public override void CommitEditingStyle(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCellEditingStyle editingStyle, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete)
            {
                var item = (MyItemType)GetItemAt(indexPath);
                viewModel.PleaseDeleteItemCommand.Execute(item);
            }
            base.CommitEditingStyle(tableView, editingStyle, indexPath);
        }
```

Both ways could be adapted to use declarative data-binding if preferred - just bind the relevant ViewModel side ICommand to a client side property.

---

Obviously, you could also implement the same functionality using a custom button instead of the built-in table delete button - see the video http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/uitableviewcell-using-xib-editor.html for how the Pet Shop sells kittens (which involves deleting rows).